# Adding image in ARCore database at runtime error

Tags: java, android-studio, augmented-reality, arcore

I want to add image at runtime in ARCore database. So, in my MainActivity.java, I have a button *Registered Image*, which on Click , added the image in ARCore database.

MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private CustomArFragment arFragment;
private TextView textView;
private AugmentedImageDatabase aid;
private Frame frame;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    arFragment = (CustomArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.arFragment);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

    arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addOnUpdateListener(this::onUpdate);

    findViewById(R.id.registeredBtn).setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
            return;
        }
        registeredImage();
    });
}

private static byte[] NV21toJPEG(byte[] nv21, int width, int height) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    YuvImage yuv = new YuvImage(nv21, ImageFormat.NV21, width, height, null);
    yuv.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 100, out);
    return out.toByteArray();
}

private static byte[] YUV_420_888toNV21(Image image) {
    byte[] nv21;
    ByteBuffer yBuffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
    ByteBuffer uBuffer = image.getPlanes()[1].getBuffer();
    ByteBuffer vBuffer = image.getPlanes()[2].getBuffer();

    int ySize = yBuffer.remaining();
    int uSize = uBuffer.remaining();
    int vSize = vBuffer.remaining();

    nv21 = new byte[ySize + uSize + vSize];

    //U and V are swapped
    yBuffer.get(nv21, 0, ySize);
    vBuffer.get(nv21, ySize, vSize);
    uBuffer.get(nv21, ySize + vSize, uSize);

    return nv21;
}

// This function triggered when Registered image button clicked
private void registeredImage() {

    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/db.imgdb");
    Frame CurrFrame = frame;
    Image currentImage;
    int idx = -1;

    try {
        currentImage = CurrFrame.acquireCameraImage();

        byte[] data = null;
        data = NV21toJPEG(YUV_420_888toNV21(currentImage),
                currentImage.getWidth(), currentImage.getHeight());

       
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length);
        idx = aid.addImage("earth",bitmap);
        aid.serialize(outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "image Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    } catch (NotYetAvailableException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
private void onUpdate(FrameTime frameTime) {
        frame = arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();
        Collection<AugmentedImage> images = frame.getUpdatedTrackables(AugmentedImage.class);
        for(AugmentedImage image : images){
            if(image.getTrackingMethod() == AugmentedImage.TrackingMethod.FULL_TRACKING){
                if(image.getName().equals("test")){
                    textView.setText("Test is visible");

                }
                else if(image.getName().equals("earth")){
                    textView.setText("earth is visible");
                }
            }
        }
}

}
```

When I clicked on button, the app crashes and image didnot add in database. Following are the errors when **idx = aid.addImage("earth",bitmap);** line called in registeredImage() function.

```
2020-10-05 14:11:39.738 31013-31013/com.example.artag E/native: error_policy_util.cc:261 
################ ARCore Native Error ##################
BUILD_CHANGELIST:331869482
BUILD_BASELINE_CHANGELIST:331085015
################### Stack Trace Begin ################
ARCoreError: third_party/arcore/ar/planar_targets/augmented_image_database_utils.cc:58  https://cs.corp.google.com/piper///depot/google3/third_party/arcore/ar/planar_targets/augmented_image_database_utils.cc?g=0&l=58
ARCoreError: third_party/arcore/ar/core/c_api/augmented_image_database_c_api.cc:133 https://cs.corp.google.com/piper///depot/google3/third_party/arcore/ar/core/c_api/augmented_image_database_c_api.cc?g=0&l=133
################### Stack Trace End #################
2020-10-05 14:11:39.739 31013-31013/com.example.artag D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-10-05 14:11:39.742 31013-31013/com.example.artag E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.artag, PID: 31013
com.google.ar.core.exceptions.ImageInsufficientQualityException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at com.google.ar.core.Session.throwExceptionFromArStatus(Session.java:101)
    at com.google.ar.core.AugmentedImageDatabase.nativeAddImage(Native Method)
    at com.google.ar.core.AugmentedImageDatabase.addImage(AugmentedImageDatabase.java:5)
    at com.example.artag.MainActivity.registeredImage(MainActivity.java:130)
    at com.example.artag.MainActivity.lambda$onCreate$0$MainActivity(MainActivity.java:72)
    at com.example.artag.-$$Lambda$MainActivity$5zEkixen6UibjSKLs5AkDUICWdM.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7333)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14160)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7299)
    at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27773)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6990)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

Please help to find out the problem,

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image that you attempted to add to the database does not have enough features.

Check https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/exceptions/ImageInsufficientQualityException#ImageInsufficientQualityException()
for the complete specification of the errors.

If you want users to upload images, I recommend using a try-catch-block and letting the user know about the error instead of having the app crash.

Comment: Hi @Meiswjn, Thanks for the answer. I added the **ImageInsufficientQualityException** in my catch block and now the app is not crashing.

Comment: And I have another doubt, After adding this exception, the steps that i'm doing of adding the image is correct?? Or there is some better way to do that??

Comment: I would try it with a picture with more features.. here you can read more: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/augmented-images#tips_for_selecting_reference_images

Comment: There is still one more problem. Whenever some error occur in try block while adding image(error because of image not have enough features), all the previous stored images in database gets automatically deleted. I am saving the database in device local memory.

Comment: Hm, interesting. Try to save the database in the finally-block? That will ALWAYS save the pictures, whether an error occurs or not. Make sure that the try / catch is as small as possible

Comment: is there any way, I can calculate the quality score(0-100) of image before adding the image to database?? because if image quality score will not enough, then i won't add that image in databse.

Comment: I am not an expert on this field, but this looks good: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/augmented-images/arcoreimg